# Toggle between multiple divs jQuery

Tags: html, toggle, alternate

Between alternate divs with id's 1-3 how do I show the visability between each one when the user clicks the corresponding link? I only want one div to be shown at a time. Thanks.

```
<a>Link 1</a><br>
<a>Link 2</a><br>
<a>Link 3</a><br>

<div id="1">
    <p align="left">Content 1</p>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <p align="left">Content 2</p>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <p align="left">Content 3</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add id's to your links so that you can add event handlers.  Assuming you set your link id's to Link1, Link2, Link3, use the following code to wire up the event handlers:

```
$("#Link1").bind("click", function() {
   $("#1").show();
   $("#2").hide();
   $("#3").hide();
});
```

Code the event handler above for the other links (2 & 3), adjusting the logic so it shows the corresponding div, and hides the others.

A more robust solution:

```
<a class="myLink" divId="1">Link 1</a>

$(".myLink").bind("click", function() {
   $(".myDiv").hide();
   var divId = $(this).attr("divId");
   $("#" + divId).show();
});
```

Assuming your add the class "myDiv" to all your divs and the class "myLink" to all your links.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8XZKx/1/

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is if I want to extend the amount of divs to say 20 or more there would be lots of duplicate code.

Comment: I like the idea of $(".myDivs").hide(); do you have a quick working example?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks SimulatedBones, just what I was looking for